# C++ how to sort a tuple based on the first, then second, then third

Tags: c++

The code will sort a std::pair based on the first elements and then the second (if the first elements are equal).

Could anybody show me how I could sort based on the third element using a tuple? if the first and second happen to be equal?

What  would like to know is how to use a predicate to sort based on the first, then second (if the first is equal) then third( if the first and second is equal)?

For example if I had:

```
(3,2,3)
(1,1,0)
(1,1,1)
(2,2,2)
```

It would print:

```
(1,1,0)
(1,1,1)
(2,2,2)
(3,2,3)
```

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>

typedef std::pair<double, double> my_pair;

struct sort_pred
{
    bool operator ()( const my_pair &left, const my_pair &right ) const
    {
        return ( left.first < right.first ) || 
               ( !( right.first < left.first ) && ( right.second > left.second ) );
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<my_pair> data;

    data.push_back( my_pair( 3, 2 ) );
    data.push_back( my_pair( 1, 2 ) );
    data.push_back( my_pair( 1, 1 ) );
    data.push_back( my_pair( 2, 2 ) );

    std::stable_sort( data.begin(), data.end(), sort_pred() );

    for ( const auto &p : data ) std::cout << p.first << ' ' << p.second << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: put them in a `std::tuple`, and then call `std::sort`?

Comment: It works like that already.

Comment: You write "then the second (if the first elements are equal)" and then do something different in the code. Did you mean `left.first < right.first || (left.first == right.first && right.second > left.second)` ?

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. The OP is relying on short circuit evaluation in conjunction with strict weak ordering. If `left.first < right.first` is false, then `!(right.first < left.first)` being true implies equivalence i.e. `left.first == right.first`. It may seem odd, but consider a scenario where only `operator<` is defined for the underlying object type (i.e. there is no direct `operator ==`). A SWO can imply such equivalence using strictly `operator <` in the manner the OP is demonstrating.

Comment: Have you tried sorting a `vector<tuple<int,int,int>>` without a predicate and seeing what happens?

Comment: ...like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/dbWe5e)?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I'm not even sure if you should write this as an answer. This shouldn't even be a question in the first place :p

Comment: @cigien :-) I'm not going to write it as an answer since I suspect there's something more hidden in this question.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Agreed. Sounds like the question needs details or clarity.

Comment: I'm sorry I've I annoyed people. What I really went to ask was how to do this using a predicate.I wanted to know how to use a predicate to sort based on the first, then second (if the first is equal) then third( if the first and second is equal)? I update my question to reflect what I really wanted to learn.

Comment: @user12660947 Why do you need a predicate at all?  `std::pair` and `std::tuple` already have `operator<` implemented to compare values the way you describe. So what's wrong with letting `std::sort()` do its default sorting without using a custom predicate?

Comment: @user12660947 You may (and probably should) ask followup questions to answers you've gotten if the answers you've gotten doesn't sort things out. Please do ask. Right now, you have an open question (this one). If I didn't explain it well, I'd like to hear about that so I can improve my answers in the future.

Answer (score 2):

> What would like to know is how to use a predicate to sort based on the first, then second (if the first is equal) then third( if the first and second is equal)?

A `std::tuple` already has an `operator<` that does the above but to do it manually, what people mostly use for this is [`std::tie`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie), which itself creates a tuple of the supplied arguments. The compare functor for a class with three fields (`f1`-`f3`) could then be:

```
[](auto& a, auto& b) { return std::tie(a.f1, a.f2, a.f3) < std::tie(b.f1, b.f2, b.f3); }
```

For the sake of showing something different, let's say that you want an ascending sort order for the first two fields, but a decending order for the last field.

Note that I've swapped place between `a` and `b` in `std::get<2>`:

```
auto comp = [](auto& a, auto& b) {
    return
        std::tie(std::get<0>(a), std::get<1>(a), std::get<2>(b))
        <
        std::tie(std::get<0>(b), std::get<1>(b), std::get<2>(a));
};

std::sort(data.begin(), data.end(), comp);
```

This would give you this order:

```
1,1,1
1,1,0
2,2,2
3,2,3
```

Swap `a` and `b` in `std::get<2>` back and you'll get the same order as your original tuple already has built-in.

If you want to do it without the help from `std::tie` you could do it like this:

```cpp
struct sort_pred {
    bool operator ()(const my_tuple& left, const my_tuple& right) const {
        if(std::get<0>(left) != std::get<0>(right)) 
            return std::get<0>(left) < std::get<0>(right);

        if(std::get<1>(left) != std::get<1>(right))
            return std::get<1>(left) < std::get<1>(right);

        return std::get<2>(left) < std::get<2>(right);
    }
};
```

Or if you want it with a lot of ternary operators, you can do that too. I find it a little harder to read, but it's a matter of taste I guess:

```
struct sort_pred {
    bool operator ()(const my_tuple& left, const my_tuple& right) const {
        return 
            std::get<0>(left) != std::get<0>(right) ? std::get<0>(left) < std::get<0>(right) :
            std::get<1>(left) != std::get<1>(right) ? std::get<1>(left) < std::get<1>(right) :
            std::get<2>(left) < std::get<2>(right);
    }
};
```

Comment: Alternative suggestion: just use `std::tuple` to start with, instead of `std::tie`

Comment: @MooingDuck Yeah, I don't really know if there are pros and cons with doing it one way or the other. `std::tie` is nice an short, so that's a bonus. :)